# Seeking free basemaps for offline use in GIS?

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap

**Situation**: I will be traveling in the next months and therefore, I have created a bunch of geolocated POIs and other layers, such as campgrounds, attractions, hiking trails and so on. I want to use these layers as my own information source either within a GIS (ArcGIS, QGIS) or building a web app with Leaflet. I can use the layers as .shp, .kml, .csv, .json, or any other vector format.

**Problem**: I need to use the data offline, as I often won't have Internet access. The main problem is, that I need any kind of **offline base map**, when visualizing my data. For OSM data, only vector data of layers are provided that can be downloaded.

Do you know of any other sources?

Comment: Maybe you can interface with [Osmand](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand.plus) in someway? You're not telling us in what format(s) that *bunch of geolocated POIs and other layers* are in...

Comment: I can use the layers as .shp, .kml, .csv, .json, or any other vector format.

Comment: Why does Open Street Map not provide a basemap, that can be downloaded as background, but only vector data?

Comment: maybe not helpful, but perhaps creating pwa in this instance is ideal, considering you are planning on not having www access. i'm not sure how feasible that is with maps currently, but sounds right.

Comment: How large an area do you need, and where in the world is it? If it's a relatively small area, all you need is a few georeferenced rasters, eg [USGS topo quads](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/how-do-i-find-and-download-us-topo-maps-and-historical-topographic-maps).

Comment: If you want to work in ArcGIS, check out this article: [FAQ: Can basemaps be used without an internet connection?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012114).

Comment: I need completely the area of North America (Canada and USA)

Comment: You could download the OSM .pbf file and generate your own tiles, thought that would take a good chunk of time and space.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to go for Leaflet and offline (Raster) Tiles, you can checkout https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles

For non-commercial products you can get free map tiles from https://openmaptiles.org/ (sign-up required).

Comment: good to know how to include mbtiles in Leaflet, but where can I get raster tiles from?

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to mention that. Checkout https://openmaptiles.org/, great stuff. I updated the answer.